# Как соединить React и Spring Boot Rest?

Tags: java, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

у меня есть приложение, рест апи на джаве, реакт посылает запросы туда и получает данные. Реакт запускается на нод джс, можно ли как нибудь настроить одну точку доступа ( чтобы зайдя на порт 8080, работало и то, и другое? Может для этого нужен какой нибудь nginx?

Comment: Нет, нужно на отдельном порту запускать spring boot приложение и на отдельном react. Клиент будет посылать запросы на url сервера. Например, если у сервер бежит на  8081 порту, то клиент будет обращаться к http://localhost:8081/ваш-путь. Если это не так, то подправьте в коде клиента.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете настроить Nginx для проксирования запросов на ваше приложение на порте 8080 и ваш сервер React на другом порте (например, порте 3000), и настроить Nginx для обслуживания клиентских запросов на порту 8080.

Вот пример конфигурации Nginx, который может использоваться для проксирования запросов на ваше приложение на порту 8080 и ваш сервер React на порту 3000:

```
server {
listen 8080;
server_name example.com;
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
}}
```

В этом примере location /api настроен для проксирования запросов на ваше приложение на порту 8080, а location / настроен для проксирования запросов на ваш сервер React на порту 3000.

Вы можете настроить этот конфигурационный файл в зависимости от вашей конкретной ситуации.

Comment: ответ от chatgpt? он ведь прямо сияет своей бесполезностью.